# TcxGrid column is hidden when dragging to group row

Tags: delphi, tcxgrid

I have two seemingly identical TcxGrids bound to two different tables.  On one grid, when the column header is dragged and dropped to the group panel, a large X appears above the column being dragged, when it is dropped the column is immediately hidden.  On the other grid a big circle with a line through it shows and it cannot be dropped on to the group panel.  The Options.Grouping for both columns is false.  Why the difference in the two behaviors ?  I cannot see a property setting difference but I'm sure there must be one somewhere that causes this behavior.  What property is it ?

John

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the properties of the column which won't group in the Object Inspector.  Probably, you'll find that its DisableGrouping property is set to True.  If it is, set it to False.  If that doesn't work, a) I'll take this answer down and b) edit your q to add the contents of your DFM.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places in DX grid that control the ability to group columns. First is at the grid level and it takes precedent over the columns' individual Options.Grouping settings. Second is at the column level. Look at .OptionCustomize.ColumnGrouping. It may be set to False.